# How do I use HuggingFace for BERT domain adaptation?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface, pre-trained-model

I am conducting [domain adaptive pretraining](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.10964) on the *bert-base-uncased* model (hosted on HuggingFace) using domain data to increase the accuracy of the model on domain specific tasks. Currently, I am not seeing any improvements in those tasks after using a domain adapted model, even after fine-tuning the adapted model. I want to confirm that I’m using Transformers correctly. Specifically:

1. Should I use *BertForMaskedLM* or *BertForPreTraining* as my starting model?
2. Should I train a tokenizer from scratch on the domain data or use a preexisting one?
3. Is having ~1M text records (each around a paragraph in length) roughly enough for continual pretraining?

I've tried using a domain adapted model and then loading it using *from_pretrained* into a text classification task, but my test set scores (acc/F1) barely change compared to just using vanilla bert. How can I gauge that my domain adapted model is meaningfully different from the standard Bert model?

Comment: for what purpose are you training? do you want to use that fine tuned model for any specific purpose?

Comment: I want to use the domain adapted model for various downstream tasks, primarily text classification

Comment: In my case I used `AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained` and used `roberta-base` as a model, the accuracy was quite good.